# Camera Module at high resolution, preview screen goes black

Tags: raspbian, picamera

Tech spec:

- Raspberry Pi4 8G RAM
- OS: Raspbian 10

**Problem Background**:

When I set resolution at `camera.resolution = (4056, 3040)`, then at `camera.start_preview()`, the preview screen is completely black.

At lower resolution, I set at `camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)`, I am able to see preview.

Answer (score 1):

A bullet form the Hardware Limits section the [picamera documentation](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/tree/release-1.13/docs):

> - The maximum resolution of the V2 camera can also cause issues with previews. Currently, picamera runs previews at the same resolution as captures (equivalent to -fp in raspistill). You may need to increase gpu_mem in /boot/config.txt to achieve full resolution operation with the V2 camera module, or configure the preview to use a lower resolution than the camera itself.